# Why are we doing so in nested foreach loop? I can't understand I am lost

Tags: c#-4.0, foreach

I can't grasp the nested foreach loop. Anyone to simplify this for me? I am learning foreach loops in C# but am stuck. What is the logic behind this?

```
class SudokuFileReader
{
    public int[,] ReadFile(string fileName)
    {
      int[,] sudokuBoard = new int[9, 9];
      try
       {
          var sudokuBoardLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

          int row = 0;

          foreach (var sudokuBoardLine in sudokuBoardLines)
            {
                string[] sudokuBoardLineElements = sudokuBoardLine.Split('|').Skip(1).Take(9).ToArray();

                int col = 0;

                foreach (var sudokuLineElement in sudokuBoardLineElements)
                    {
                        sudokuBoard[row, col] = sudokuLineElement.Equals(" ") ? 0 : Convert.ToInt16(sudokuLineElement);
                        col++;
                    }

                    row++;
             }

         }
        catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    throw new Exception("Something went wrong while reading the file: " + ex.Message);
                }

        return sudokuBoard;
       }
}
```

Comment: I advice you to go through the code with the debugger, that way you can figure out much better whats going on. In this case, you are filling the sudoku board from the top, beginning with line 1. In line one you get all nine numbers and fill from left to right. When no numbers are left you leave the inner for loop and increase the line, therefore now filling line 2 and so on